# Primer ejercicio POO. Esta bien estructurado?

Tags: java, poo

Me gustaria saber si esta bien planteado y estructurado este primer ejercicio en poo.

```
package oscove.ejerciciosBasicos.POO;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangulo {
    int base,altura;

    public int obtenerBase(){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce la base: ");
        return (base = entrada.nextInt());

    }
    public int obtenerAltura(){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce la altura: ");
        return (altura = entrada.nextInt());
    }
    public void calculaAreas(){
        System.out.println("El area de rectangulo es: " + base * altura+ " mts2");
        System.out.println("El perimetro del rectangulo es: "+(base + altura)*2 +" mts.");
    }
}
```

Metodo Main

```
package oscove.ejerciciosBasicos.POO;

public class pruebaRectangulo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangulo rectangulo = new Rectangulo();
        rectangulo.obtenerAltura();
        rectangulo.obtenerBase();
        rectangulo.calculaAreas();
    }
```

Comment: Que quieres optimizar del programa? Es importante que seas especifico en tu problema.

Answer (score 3):

No, una mejor estructuración sería así:

**Rectangulo**

```
package oscove.ejerciciosBasicos.POO;

public class Rectangulo {
    private int base;
    private int altura;

    public Rectangulo(int base, int altura){
        this.base = base;
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    public int getBase(){
        return this.base

    }
    public int getAltura(){
        return this.altura;
    }

    public int getArea(){
        return (base * altura);
    }

    public int getPerimetro(){
        return ((base + altura)*2);
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
package oscove.ejerciciosBasicos.POO;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class pruebaRectangulo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce la base: ");
        int base = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce la altura: ");
        int altura = entrada.nextInt();

        Rectangulo rectangulo = new Rectangulo(base, altura);

         System.out.println("El area de rectangulo es: " + rectangulo.getArea() + " mts2");
         System.out.println("El perimetro del rectangulo es: " + rectangulo.getPerimetro() + " mts.");
    }
```

Las lecturas por pantalla las debes hacer en el main. Y entonces le tendrá que pasar los parámetros por medio del constructor al objeto Rectangulo.

Tambien es mejor que las funciones de calculo del area y perimetro devuelvan un entero ya que quizas en un futuro necesites ese calculo para otras funciones y otros objetos y si devolviesen una string no podrias reutilizarla